# How to detect if a browser is a webkit based engine now $.browser is deprecated?

Tags: jquery, browser, webkit, cross-browser, deprecated

I want to detect the rendering engine of a browser (in this case webkit) in Javascript, however `$.browser` has been deprecated so I was wondering how you went about doing it now?

I've seen lots of replacements for detecting individual browsers, however I'm looking a specific alternative for `$.browser.webkit`

Thanks.

Comment: What feature are you looking for that isn't present in non-Webkit browsers?

Comment: @Blender Some rendering of line height is slightly different between gecko and webkit and I wanted it to be perfect, so I'm adding a "webkit" css class to the body tag and adding the odd bit of css here and there to tweak it in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could target it with a Webkit-only media query:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
    body {
        font-size: 200px;
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: great! don't even need javascipt